# How to make a Console plugin to interact with facebook games or other flash apps

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex

I'm playing a flash game on facebook. I know I can decompile it to find out all the commands and would like to make scripts to automate the game by calling procedures in the actionscript of the game. So I guess I would like to make a plugin also that would insert this console into any flash app and this would be handy for a lot of things. Then if anyone wants to hack a new game, u just decompile it and make a handbook of methods for people to make scripts with. So how would I go about making this console? I don't know if I could make a swf interact with the game or if it has to be compiled into the game's swf. Or if it is easier with javascript, that is cool too. maybe we can make a javascript library just for this. anyone can tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't do this, the Flash security model won't allow it.

The console would need to be compiled into the original SWF, which you could only do as the original swf author.

Comment: well, someone already made a bot for a similar game using flex but u weren't able to use the original game player, u would use the player they made which was a different interface and couldn't be logged into both at the same time but I'm sure somehow u can make a console instead even if I would have to compile it into the games player. it's easy to decompile and even easy to read actionscript. The other bot was called Evobot for a game called Evony. I still have the source code for Evobot.

Comment: Post the source somewhere or provide a link, I can certainly tell you how it's getting around the sandbox security.

Comment: Most likely the Evobot talks to the server in the same way as the flash game itself, however, without seeing it myself, I can't say how it does it. What I do know is you can't inject code into a SWF you don't have control over.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could interact with the original game servers as the flash (.swf File) does it.

I tried it too, but it is pretty tricky because some parts of the package content is being encrypted.

I don't know how to decompile the game files so you could maybe write the same algorithm inside your program and communicate with the servers. Clientless.